# Angular error handling and propagation between component and service

Tags: angular

I have a recipe-edit component, in which i submit a form to update a recipe, the code for the .ts file looks something like this

```
onSubmit(){
    const newRecipe = new Recipe(...params fo the recipe);
      try{
        this.recipeService.updateRecipe(this.id,newRecipe);
      } catch (error){
        console.log(error);
      }
  }
```

And the recipeService that i call to make the update has an update recipe method that looks like this

```
updateRecipe(index: number, newRecipe: Recipe){
    return this.http.put<string>('http://localhost:3005/api/recipes/'+ index,newRecipe)
      .pipe(
        catchError((error) => {
          return throwError(() => error);
        })
      )
      .subscribe(() => {
        this.recipes[index] = newRecipe;
      })
}
```

I want to handle the error that i throw in the service, but in the component, so that i can display it in my interface, but this implementation doesnt work, any suggestions on how to improve/fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code in the service file:

```
updateRecipe(index: number, newRecipe: Recipe){
    return this.http.put('http://localhost:3005/api/recipes/'+ index,newRecipe);
}
```

and this in the Component:

```
onSubmit(){
    const newRecipe = new Recipe(...params fo the recipe);
    try{
        this.recipeService.updateRecipe(this.id,newRecipe).subscribe((response:any) => {
            console.log(response)
        },(error:any) => {
            console.log(error)
        });
    } catch (error){
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, could you tell me what's the difference between error:any => {} and the enxt catch error? When will they be triggered?

Comment: Check this link "https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/angular-http-error-handling/"